# Javascript from Variable textbox

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP page including Javascript,

my issue that I need to calculate textboxs in other textbox on same page ,
if count of textboxs is fixed its true working like

```
allval=allval+parseFloat(theForm5.totmountx1.value); 
allval=allval+parseFloat(theForm5.totmountx2.value); 
allval=allval+parseFloat(theForm5.totmountx3.value); 
allval=allval+parseFloat(theForm5.totmountx4.value);
```

---

but my totmountx have variable number depends on user inputs , 
i tried to write , but its not working ,

enter code here

```
for (var i=1;i<=seq;i++)
{
var allval=allval+parseFloat(theForm5.totmountx+i.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
theForm5['totmountx'+ i].value
```

Also, it should be:

```
var allval = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= seq; i++) {
    allval += parseFloat(theForm5['totmountx'+ i].value);
}
```

Otherwise you try to initialize the variable multiple times.

Comment: For more information about types of notation, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406